# Modelling of sensor noise

Tags: gazebo-sensor, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm quite used to Gazebo in ROS Electric. In URDF, there is possibility to set desired level of Gaussian noise for laser scanner and IMU, distortion for camera etc. I went through specification of SDF and there are no such elements... So I'm wondering if it's going to be specified later or never. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/611/modelling-of-sensor-noise/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1314/balakumar-s/) on 2015-08-15**:
Hey, did you find a way to implement a noise model? I am simulating kinect in gazebo and am looking for a noise model that matches the actual kinect hardware. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sensor noise models are planned to be released sometime before this year is out. We highly encourage you to take a stab at this.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-01-10**:
Actually, I'm quite interested in modelling sensor noise and errors as it's part of my research for PhD. thesis. I've already implemented some basic noise model for Kinect depth measurement.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-01-10**:
Is there any SIG (or something like this) for this kind of functionality?